# Bond two Internet connections for stability, without breaking sessions

Tags: linux, networking

My house has a fixed VDSL2 connection and I also have a mobile LTE connection. Both have reasonably good bandwidth, but every now and then both of them reset and take some amount of time (more or less a minute) to be working again. This is not a problem for normal usage, but sometimes (when broadcasting an important live session through YouTube) I really need a connection which is as stable as possible. The connection to the YouTube server is a TCP session with RTMP running over it.

I can count on a remote Linux server with stable connection and a fixed IP. I would like to bond the two connections so that a local service receives the RTMP connection from the broadcasting software and duplicate it towards the remote server through both available connections. The remote server has a companion service which receives both connections and holds the connection to the YouTube server, forwarding to it the data. Some thing happening for data in the other sense. When a connection goes down, the data still flows through the other one, and the local service continuously tries to recover the fallen connection.

Is there some program already that does this thing or something similar?

Comment: You could use MPTCP between your client and your Linux server, and run some kind of YouTube-compatible connection proxy service on your Linux server. It sounds like some researchers did something similar: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8384187

Comment: The million dollar question is can the resets be seen and triggered in realtime? If not you likely need to  duplicate all traffic. I didnt succeed with this duplicate traffic step last time I had the issue but I'm fairly sure if you can work out how to do it, you can set up 2 openVPN connection (one through each connection), then see send a packet down each VPN, then ignore the DUP.  A VPN is needed because of egress filtering if you send packets out raw tunnels.

Comment: @davidgo Duplicating all the traffic is acceptable for me, if it allows me to have a more stable connection.